# Kafka is giving: "The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka to consume messages in Java.  I want to test by starting the same app multiple times on my local box. When I start up, the first time I am able to start consuming messages from the topic.  When I start up a second one I get:

```
Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
```

and dont get any messages from the topic.  If I try to start more of them I get the same issues.

The configuration I am using for Kafka is

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
      properties:
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        spring.json.use.type.headers: false
    listener:
      missing-topics-fatal: false
```

I have two topics

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopics {
    @Bean("alertsTopic")
    public NewTopic alertsTopic() {

        return TopicBuilder.name("XXX.alerts")
            .compact()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("serversTopic")
    public NewTopic serversTopic() {

        return TopicBuilder.name("XXX.servers")
            .compact()
            .build();
    }

}
```

And two listeners in *different* class files.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = SERVERS_KAFKA_TOPIC, id = "#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}",
    properties = {
        "spring.json.key.default.type=java.lang.String",
        "spring.json.value.default.type=com.devhaus.learningjungle.db.kafka.ServerInfo"
    })
public void registerServer(
    @Payload(required = false) ServerInfo serverInfo
) 

@KafkaListener(topics = ALERTS_KAFKA_TOPIC,
    id = "#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}",
    properties = {
        "spring.json.key.default.type=com.devhaus.learningjungle.db.kafka.AlertOnKafkaKey",
        "spring.json.value.default.type=com.devhaus.learningjungle.db.kafka.AlertOnKafka"
    })
public void processAlert(
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) AlertOnKafkaKey key,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partitionId,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset,
    @Payload(required = false) AlertOnKafka alert)
```

Comment: can you show some code and how you set the ConsumerGroup?

Comment: I just got this when I set up a new environment.  But this may help.  Going to see if I missed this setting https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-394%3A+Require+member.id+for+initial+join+group+request

Comment: I'm adding my config maybe it's similar to yours.

Answer (score 20):

From my analysis.  This is normal behaviour, you can change the log levels to exclude it.

The reason for this is if the server detects that the client can support `member.id` it will give that error back to the client.  This is noted in [KIP-394](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-394%3A+Require+member.id+for+initial+join+group+request).

The client will then reconnect back to the server with a generated member ID.

Comment: this seems to prevent my consumer from consuming.. do you know how can i properly set this up?

Comment: for me, i get this error even when reading using single instance of my application but it does not effect my consumer.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience this is caused by a missing group instance id configuration.

Below is what I use while configuring the kafka consumer for a group.

```
consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_INSTANCE_ID_CONFIG,("SchedulerCoordinator"+UUID.randomUUID()));
```

Bear in mind that I personally prefer class configurations over property based ones and these consumerProperties go into the Consumer initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer from @Archimedes Trajano doesn't work for you (like in my case), then this happens when kafka can't pick up the consumer group id.

if you have a single consumer group, you can specify it in the properties file like this:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: insert-your-consumer-group-id
      ... rest of your properties ...
```

or if you have multiple consumers then you can specify the `groupId` for each one:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics="topic-1", groupId="group-1")
public void registerServer(@Payload(required = false) ServerInfo serverInfo) 

@KafkaListener(topics="topic-2",groupId="group-2")
public void processAlert(@Payload(required = false) AlertOnKafka alert)
```

docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-properties

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, also preventing my consumer from subscribing to certain topics.

I figured that the member.id *might* be similar to the client-id (using Camel here), which might be in some way related to the consumer group.

What fixed it for me is a changed, this time non-changing client-id for my consuming service, leaving the same consumer group as is.

Answer (score 0):

hummm....in my case, consumers will rejoin the group with a generated ID. Here is my test and result. FYI

```java
@Test
    void testSyncSend() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        int id = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
        SendResult result = producer.syncSend(id);
        logger.info("[testSyncSend] id:{}, result:{}", id, result);
        new CountDownLatch(1).await();
    }
```

```
2021-04-20 14:32:20.980  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.1
2021-04-20 14:32:20.981  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 0efa8fb0f4c73d92
2021-04-20 14:32:20.981  INFO 6672 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1618900340980
2021-04-20 14:32:21.125  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Cluster ID: RctzTn4XR4WNNVuqh25izw
2021-04-20 14:32:21.125  INFO 6672 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: RctzTn4XR4WNNVuqh25izw
2021-04-20 14:32:21.125  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Cluster ID: RctzTn4XR4WNNVuqh25izw
2021-04-20 14:32:21.125  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Cluster ID: RctzTn4XR4WNNVuqh25izw
2021-04-20 14:32:21.125  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Cluster ID: RctzTn4XR4WNNVuqh25izw
2021-04-20 14:32:21.127  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Discovered group coordinator localhost:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2021-04-20 14:32:21.127  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Discovered group coordinator localhost:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2021-04-20 14:32:21.127  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Discovered group coordinator localhost:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2021-04-20 14:32:21.127  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Discovered group coordinator localhost:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2021-04-20 14:32:21.130  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.130  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.130  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.130  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.147  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.147  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.147  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.147  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.148  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.148  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.148  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.148  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] (Re-)joining group
2021-04-20 14:32:21.317  INFO 6672 --- [           main] c.z.s.cbaConnector.KafkaProducerTest     : [testSyncSend] id:1618900340, result:SendResult [producerRecord=ProducerRecord(topic=test1, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 122, 104, 105, 108, 105, 46, 115, 109, 115, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 46, 101, 110, 116, 105, 116, 121, 46, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101])], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=Message(id=1618900340), timestamp=null), recordMetadata=test1-1@0]
2021-04-20 14:32:23.770  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Finished assignment for group at generation 2: {consumer-listener1-4-9a383250-e84d-413a-b012-85405abdcf7f=Assignment(partitions=[test1-8, test1-9]), consumer-listener1-2-3d26d9ef-b973-4d19-a930-5ba77d938680=Assignment(partitions=[test1-3, test1-4, test1-5]), consumer-listener1-1-10b6895e-264e-45bd-ba90-c71ea12b21e5=Assignment(partitions=[test1-0, test1-1, test1-2]), consumer-listener1-3-54ce965a-87cd-4e28-b0e9-b0f2c9f69423=Assignment(partitions=[test1-6, test1-7])}
2021-04-20 14:32:23.775  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Successfully joined group with generation 2
2021-04-20 14:32:23.775  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Successfully joined group with generation 2
2021-04-20 14:32:23.775  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Successfully joined group with generation 2
2021-04-20 14:32:23.776  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Successfully joined group with generation 2
2021-04-20 14:32:23.779  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Adding newly assigned partitions: test1-5, test1-4, test1-3
2021-04-20 14:32:23.779  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Adding newly assigned partitions: test1-6, test1-7
2021-04-20 14:32:23.779  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Adding newly assigned partitions: test1-0, test1-2, test1-1
2021-04-20 14:32:23.779  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Adding newly assigned partitions: test1-9, test1-8
2021-04-20 14:32:23.789  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Found no committed offset for partition test1-8
2021-04-20 14:32:23.789  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Found no committed offset for partition test1-6
2021-04-20 14:32:23.789  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Found no committed offset for partition test1-2
2021-04-20 14:32:23.789  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Found no committed offset for partition test1-1
2021-04-20 14:32:23.791  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Setting offset for partition test1-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=14, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2021-04-20 14:32:23.791  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Setting offset for partition test1-5 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2021-04-20 14:32:23.791  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Setting offset for partition test1-9 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2021-04-20 14:32:23.791  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Setting offset for partition test1-7 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2021-04-20 14:32:23.791  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Setting offset for partition test1-4 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2021-04-20 14:32:23.791  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-2, groupId=listener1] Setting offset for partition test1-3 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2021-04-20 14:32:23.792  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-1-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : listener1: partitions assigned: [test1-5, test1-4, test1-3]
2021-04-20 14:32:23.804  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-4, groupId=listener1] Resetting offset for partition test1-8 to offset 0.
2021-04-20 14:32:23.804  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-3, groupId=listener1] Resetting offset for partition test1-6 to offset 0.
2021-04-20 14:32:23.804  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Resetting offset for partition test1-2 to offset 0.
2021-04-20 14:32:23.804  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-listener1-1, groupId=listener1] Resetting offset for partition test1-1 to offset 0.
2021-04-20 14:32:23.804  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-3-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : listener1: partitions assigned: [test1-9, test1-8]
2021-04-20 14:32:23.804  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-2-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : listener1: partitions assigned: [test1-6, test1-7]
2021-04-20 14:32:23.804  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : listener1: partitions assigned: [test1-0, test1-2, test1-1]
2021-04-20 14:32:23.817  INFO 6672 --- [listener1-0-C-1] c.z.s.cbaConnector.KafkaConsumer         : [KafakaConsumer][consume] thread:21 received message:{"id":1618900340}
```