# Lag in spring boot kafka consumer? how to fix?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I work with the spring boot service consumes messages from kafka. It often happens service remains in working state, but messages from the topic are not consuming and the lag is increasing in this consumer-group for this topic, why it happening? Why there is no consumer`s reconnection? Is it possible to configure it?

update : 03-08-2021.

{"@timestamp":"2021-07-31T02:59:12.086+00:00","@version":"1","message":"[Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=common] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator","thread_name":"KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='notificator.in', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}.container-0-C-1","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"app-name":"unknown","app-version":"unknown"}

Comment: Sounds like the consumer thread is dying, and you'd need to provide logs/metrics for us to really tell you why and how to fix

Comment: i ve seen this log message when this happened. What does it mean ?

Comment: Seems to be something about `member.id` consumer setting -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946696/kafka-is-giving-the-group-member-needs-to-have-a-valid-member-id-before-actual

Comment: thanks. reason of this lag was found. Spring did not send acknowledgment